# Reference to a static, function local variable

Tags: c++

Is the following code considered safe?

```
Foo& GetFoo()
{
    static std::once_flag fooInitFlag;
    static Foo f;

    std::call_once(fooInitFlag, [&Foo]()
    {
       Foo.Init();
    });

    return std::ref(f);

}
```

Comment: You don't need the `once_flag` thing. A single initialization is guaranteed. Use constructor, not `Init` method-

Comment: Yes. Note you still need that in msvc 2013 but not in C++11 conform compiler where static initialization is thread safe. (do not return std::ref(f), just f)

Comment: You don't need `std::ref` here; just return `f`. And it's safe, since `f` will remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> Is the following code considered safe?

The answer is yes.

Another implementation:

```
// Not exposed to the outside.
static Foo& getInitializedFoo();
{
    static Foo f;
    f.Init();
    return f;
}

Foo& GetFoo()
{
    static Foo& f = getInitializedFoo();
    return f;
}
```

Comment: how about, `static Foo&` (reference), to avoid the copying. I think it's just a typo.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I meant the helper function to return an object by value.

Comment: Well, it would work just as well with a reference (same initialization guarantee), `static` Foo, and more efficient + less chance of side-effect. Downside that `getInitializedFoo` then is an internal implementation detail, to only be called once.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I see.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this posted code:

```
Foo& GetFoo()
{
    static std::once_flag fooInitFlag;
    static Foo f;

    std::call_once(fooInitFlag, [&Foo]()
    {
       Foo.Init();
    });

    return std::ref(f);
}
```

do this:

```
struct Initialized_foo
{
    Foo item;
    Initialized_foo() { item.Init(); }
};

auto get_foo()
    -> Foo&
{
    static Initialized_foo the_foo;
    return the_foo.item;
}
```

It's not more safe, but it's simpler, and hence more safe against inadvertently introduced bugs.

Note that the standard guarantees a single initialization here, even in the context of multi-threading.

---

Better, ideally each `Foo` insteance should be properly initialized by the `Foo` constructor, not by an `Init` method. But that's not always possible to arrange.

Comment: You forgot `the_foo.item`

Comment: And `static Initialized_foo the_foo;`.

Comment: @RSahu: thanks, again. hm. maybe should turn off the TV.

Comment: @tom: I reverted your pure coding style edit. Please don't do that. No need for braces wars and all that.